# Wordpress Woocommerce shop page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I need help adding VIEW and ADD button into my Woocommerce Shop page. Do you have any plugins or codes that I can add into my functions.php?

Comment: please elaborate more cant understand what are you saying.... where does VIEW button goes to and ADD button l

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to add add to cart and view button in shop page

```
//// to add cart buttton
function add_cart_to_shop () {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_cart_to_shop' );

//// to add view buttton
function add_view_to_shop() {
  echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" class="view-product">View</a>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_view_to_shop', 8 );
```

Try this then let me know the result.
You need css code to design it yourself.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot Souvik Sikdar. it works perfect